# Mix up two responses

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm facing a funny issue with WCF response serialization.
After a number of requests (let's say 10), WCF starts to mix-up requests and always after the 128th character when using Utf8 encoding.

Expected response:

```
<via version="1.1">
    <response>
        <status code="0" />
        <res-get-balance>
            <balance value="38.65" currency="GBP" />
            <token>IQV2SSc41Fux6zWeaaUOMKtBvYW3IgtDZFJ4r1</token>
        </res-get-balance>
    </response>
</via>
```

However I got this as a response:

```
<via version="1.1">
    <response>
        <status code="0" />
        <res-get-balance>
            <balance value="38.65" currency="GBP" />
            <token>IQV2SSc41Fux6zWe
                <via version="1.1">
                    <response>
                        <status code="0" />
                        <res-get-balance>
                            <balance value="38.65" currency="GBP" />
                            <token>IQ
```

When it reaches character number 128 it starts from the beginning.

Here is my binding configuration:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingConfig" sendTimeout="05:00:00" ></binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

Here is my behavior configuration:

```
<behavior name="webXmlOverHttpBehavior">
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="165536" />
    <endpointDiscovery enabled="true" />
    <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" />
</behavior>
```

My service implementation has the following attribute:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is your XML document element `via`? Also, have you tried Fiddler to see if the response from the service is what is mangled, or whether there is a proxy server between your client and server mangling it?

Comment: Yep. Fiddler is showing me those bad responses as well.

Answer (score 0):

For WCF REST service, the default and valid InstanceContextMode is "PerCall" only.

Either it should throw error when "InstanceContextMode.Single" is set, or it should ignore it. But it is behaving differently.

So remove the InstanceContextMode and try, it should work.